# How to configure GlassFish to send email to Exim (550 authentication required)?

Tags: jakarta-mail, glassfish-3

I'm having problem to configure JavaMail session in GlassFish 3.1.1 to send email to Exim 4.76 mail server. Both GlassFish and Exim are running in the same CentOS server.

Here is my JavaMail session configuration in GlassFish:

```
JNDI Name: mail/mailSession
Mail Host: localhost
Default User: glassfish
Default Sender Address: glassfish@mycompany.com
Status: Enabled is checked
Store Protocol: IMAP
Store Protocol Class: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore
Transport Protocol: SMTP
Transport Protocol Class: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport
```

Here is the exception from GlassFish's server log:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 authentication required
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1835)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1098)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

In the same Unix user account where the GlassFish is started, I'm able to send email using the following command:

```
$ exim -v -odf dummy@gmail.com
This is a test message from server.
.
```

So I assume my Exim mail server is running correctly but my GlassFish?

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the session to use SMTP authentication.  See [this FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth).  You can set the session properties when you configure the mail session in GlassFish, and you'll need to supply the username and password when you connect to the server.